# How to use while loop in csh shell command prompt?

Tags: linux, csh

I am trying to use while loop in `csh` shell command prompt in RHEL 7.2 but am getting the below error:

```
$ while true
while: Expression Syntax.
```

The same is working in `bash` shell.

Comment: Why would you use `csh` in the 21st century, especially on a Linux distribution, especially interactively?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax of `while` loops in `csh` is different from that of Bourne-like shells. It's:

```
while (arithmetic-expression)
  body
end
```

When `csh` is interactive, for some reason, that `end` has to appear on its own on a line.

For the *arithmetic-expression* to test on the success of a command, you need `{ cmd }` (spaces are required). `{ cmd }` in arithmetic expressions resolves to 1 if the command succeeded (exited with a 0 exit status) or 0 otherwise (if the command exited with a non-zero exit status).

So:

```
while ({ true })
  body
end
```

But that would be a bit silly especially considering that `true` is not a built-in command in `csh`. For an infinite loop, you'd rather use:

```
while (1)
  body
end
```

By contrast, in POSIX shells, the syntax is:

```
while cmd; do
  body
done
```

And if you want the condition to evaluate an arithmetic expression, you need to run a command that evaluates them like `expr`, or `ksh`'s `let`/`((...))` or the `test`/`[` command combined with `$((...))` arithmetic expansions.

Answer (score 4):

```
set i = 1
while ($i < 5)
   echo "i is $i"
   @ i++
end
```

or

```
set i = 1
while (1)
    echo "i is $i"
    @ i++
    if ($i >= 5) break
end
```

These output:

```
i is 1
i is 2
i is 3
i is 4
```

`csh` is largely superseded by the `sh`-shells nowadays, especially on the Linux platform (where the use of `csh` never really was widespread to begin with). Most BSDs also offer `sh`-compatible shells as their default interactive shell.

If you're learning shell programming, do consider learning the `sh` shell, unless your work requires you to grok `csh` and `tcsh` scripts (in this case, you may use a `sh` shell, like `bash`, as your interactive shell regardless of what types of scripts you work with).

Comment: `@ i++` saved my time. I tried `set i=$i+1`, `set i=i+1`, etc. but without success. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

from the `csh shell` , `man while` page

```
set x 0
while {$x<10} {
     puts "x is $x"
     incr x
}
```

Comment: That's the TCL man page!